# Dynamically creating button elements and the event listener is called immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am creating buttons in a response to a succcessful AJAX call, and each button needs to call a function with that specific dynamic info. Here is how I am doing it right now:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < variableNames.length; i++) {

      var getInvButton = document.createElement('button');
      getInvButton.id = 'getInventoryButton';

      console.dir('Add a button with this ID: ' + variableNames[i]);

      getInvButton.addEventListener("click", function(charName, membershipName) {
           console.dir('Test button click: ' + charName);
           getInventoryVar(charName, membershipName);
      } (variableNames[i], 
 result.Response.characters.data[variableNames[i]].membershipId), false);
 }
```

I can access my variables properly, and the `getInventoryVar` is called with the right parameters for each button. However, this function is being executed immediately upon it being added.

Comment: First: Ensure that your elements have a unique id. Right now `getInvButton` has the same id for all `variableNames`. Second: Do you add the buttons anywhere to your DOM?

Comment: They button's do not have a unique ID, but they I don't that they need unique ID's. And yes I did add it to the DOM later on in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your handler like this:

```
function(charName, membershipName) {
  return function(e) {
    console.dir('Test button click: ' + charName);
    getInventoryVar(charName, membershipName);
  }                           
} (variableNames[i], result.Response.characters.data[variableNames[i]].membershipId)
```

Comment: This worked! Not 100% sure why though, is it because of the closure aspect of javascript?

Comment: It's because that way a function is returned, which is executed on click. By adding (<charname>, <membershipName>) after your function definition, the method gets executed. Therefore you returned the result of the function in your original code instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The functions that you are trying to attach `function(charName, memberShipNa...` is actually being called when you attach it. You should instead create a new function that calls this function:

```
getInvButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // old function
    function(charName, membershipName) {
       console.dir('Test button click: ' + charName);
       getInventoryVar(charName, membershipName);
  }(variableNames[i], result.Response.characters.data[variableNames[i]].membershipId);

}, false);
```

(could be more succint, but hey)